# How to dynamically make each file optional

Tags: nsis

I am currently using the following code to add all files from specified paths

```
Section

SetOutPath $InstDir
!tempfile folders ; temporary .nsh
!system 'for /D %A in (.\ParentFolder\*) do @>>"${folders}" echo File /r "%~A\Same\Path\For\All\*.ext"'
!include "${folders}"
!delfile "${folders}"

SectionEnd
```

## Question

How would I make it so that each file would have a checkbox to allow selecting individual files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial attempt of using `!system` is on the right track but you need to use `FOR /R` (or a batch file) and generate a `Section` for each file:

```
!define FOLDERwithMYFILES  "C:\stuff\myfiles"

!tempfile filesnsh
!system 'FOR /R "${FOLDERwithMYFILES}" %A in (*.*) do >>"${filesnsh}" echo Section "%~nA"&>>"${filesnsh}" File "%~A"&>>"${filesnsh}" echo SectionEnd'
!include "${filesnsh}"
!delfile "${filesnsh}"

Page Components
Page InstFiles
```